# (Co)Monads with a mixed distributive law on the 2-Category of Groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

I am looking for containers on the 2-Category of Groupoids.  In particular, though, I would like my container to be both a monad and a comonad with a mixed distributive law.  Can someone provide one or more examples of such (co)monads?

I would also like the (co)monad to have a polynomial form.